# Issue with reCaptcha submitting form on ENTER key - AJAX/JS/PHP

Tags: php, ajax, recaptcha

I have a form that will be validated with AJAX and return an error if the user makes any mistakes.

The problem is this: When the user enters the reCaptcha string and presses the ENTER key when the reCaptcha field is on focus, the form is Submitted instead of calling the specified function.

So for instance, let's say I have a form such as:

```
    <form ... onSubmit='checkform()'>
      <-- reCaptcha code goes here -->
    </form>
```

As I described, when the user hits the ENTER key on the reCaptcha field, it automatically submits the form, wihtout calling the function 'checkForm()'. (I've debugged it with alert and return false in the function, and indeed seems like reCaptcha overrides the function)

Any ideas on how to prevent this, i.e., actually force reCaptcha to call the function and only be submitted if it returns true?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `return false in the function` will not work here. only if `onsubmit='return checkform();'`

Comment: Thank you for replying, but still no luck. Pressing ENTER on reCaptcha ignores the function completely.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can remove the submit input and just use a button

```
<input type="button" value="ClickMe" onclick="checkForm();" />
```

Also remove the

```
onSubmit='checkform()'
```

Comment: reCaptcha submits the form regardless on having or missing Submit button.